# how to click on a specific record that is just entered in selenium in Divs & grids

Tags: xpath, selenium

In my application, I have an option to open the popup menu(by clicking in a specific column of table)  & then the function is called using click on any of the menu items

I added a record1, which will be appeared in table with other x,y,z records. SO now I have 4 rows in table.
I want to open popup menu of the record1(which is just created by my test) How can I do that?

All of the work in my app is done using divs. I am finding  elements through XPaths but in this scenario I am not able to do the needful.

Comment: if the new popup link is randomly created, use contains method in xpath for ex:- `//div[contains(@id,'partial id which is constant')]`

Comment: but the text i need to verify is in different column& menu option comes in different column ... I mean i need to find& verify text of two columns in a row & then click in the another column of same row

 col1 col2 col3
*(menu) rec1 rec2 rec3
*(menu) abc xyz pqr



i need to find lets se "rec1" & "rec2" row & then click on that row's menu

Comment: my problem is same like this, but i dont hv 100 records buut yes the position of the recorded row changes when i rerun the tst: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/selenium-users/kEQS2z5_zwM